# Change button value in table during clone

Tags: jquery

i have a modal with a table (image below). [image: modal image]

When i click ADD button it will clone the whole row into the table behind the modal (image below). [image: table behind modal image]

I have successfully cloned the row but **i want to change the button value of the cloned row from "ADD" to "REMOVE". How can i do it?**

> code below is how i cloned the row

```
<script>
        function addField(n)
        {
            var tr = n.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById('tbl').appendChild(tr);
        }
</script>
```

> And this is my table

```
<?php

  while($datatrack = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTrack))
     {
      echo "
       <tr>
        <td>".$datatrack['Question_ID']."</td>
        <td>".$datatrack['Question']."</td>
        <td>".$datatrack['Track_Desc']."</td>
        <td><input type='button' onclick='addField(this)' value='ADD'></td>
       </tr>";
      } 
?>
```

**How change the button value of the cloned row from "ADD" to "REMOVE"?.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply query for the button element on the `tr` variable, and then set its value:

```
<script>
    function addField(n)
    {
        var tr = n.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
        var buttonInput = tr.querySelector('[value="ADD"]');

        if (buttonInput) {
            buttonInput.value = 'REMOVE';
        }

        document.getElementById('tbl').appendChild(tr);
    }
</script>
```